# Is it possible to enforce new instance for new caller for WCF service running on IIS?

Tags: wcf, iis, instance

We have WCF service running on IIS and would like to implement caching data for separate callers so that not each request for data would need to go to database. Is there a way to enforce IIS to create separte WCF service instance for different callers?

We use LAZY creation of the cache and from logging it seems that only one instance of service is created.

Comment: Have you ever read this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-control-service-instancing

Comment: I saw the link provided by LexLi, you can try to set the ServiceBehaviorAttribute attribute of the InstanceContextMode attribute to PerCall.